Как отразить iframe в схеме потоков данных?
Вот мы выполнили интеграцию с внешней системой Икс и требуется это отобразить на схеме потоков данных.
Пользователи соединяются с нашим сайтом через nginx сервер по 80 порту.
Мы выводим на странице iframe, в котором подгружается эта внешняя система.
С точки зрения потока данных: инициатора и получателя, потоки идут по 80 порту от
пользователь -> система икс
система икс -> пользователь
или 
наша система (nginx) -> система икс
система икс -> наша система (nginx)

Ведь наша система только выводит html код iframe, а между пользователем и системой икс может быть значительный обмен трафиком.
